# Nginx subrequest response encoding issue

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have a Nginx server with location and simple NJS scenario where I need to parse the response of surequest. The response from API has such a header:

> "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8", "Cache-Control":
> "no-store", "Content-Encoding": "gzip", ...

When I am trying to read responseBody it looks like below:

> \u001f�\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0004\u0000��\u0007`\u001cI�%&/m�{J�J��t�\b�`\u0013$ؐ@\u0010������\u001diG#)�*��eVe]f\u0016@�흼��{���{���;�N'

The issue is reproducing only in NJS. It looks like an encoding issue. Is anybody knows how to fix it and parse such a response?

PS: I have tried to check JSON response from another API and got the same encoding issue. Nginx version is 1.19.1 and NJS is 0.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in gzip encoding. Decoding the response helped me. I have added this directive to location and now it's working correct.

> gunzip on;